# Drawing on Mobile with fingers: magnifier or offset from finger location?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research, mobile-application, usability-testing

We are working on a "remove objects from photos" app, where the users highlight/select a part of an image they want to remove and the app takes care of it.

Precision is sort of important here, on one hand, it's not for Pro users, it's a classic B2C mobile app.
On the other hand, we assume users want to remove specific objects, sometimes very subtle.

Currently, when the users move their finger they'll "paint" the same location on the image, which can create issues as the finger "hides" the content underneath it.
We thought about two mechanisms to improve it:

- Add Offset to the finger location:

[image]

- Same location, but you Maganfier to showcase what's below the finger:

[image]

Would love to hear you suggestions, thanks!

Comment: The second option (magnifier) is present in Samsung's camera application when "scan document" feature is used. User can adjust the crop/perspective region by dragging the corners, and the magnifier is conveniently shown in the opposite corner, so it's even further from user's fingers. I find this approach very useful for precise adjustments. In your example it moves with the finger, which I would find annoying. Is there a way to make the magnifier more static, and only move when finger is very close to it?

Comment: Hey @fri! Thanks for the suggestion, we made a magnifaier with a smooth position and that basically solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @fri, do you happen to have a video example of this behavior? on your Samsung? I have an iPhone, and there no reference of this on YouTube

Comment: Here's a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zmr5ajP6Le0 @RoiMulia

Comment: Hey @fri! Thanks. Looks good. Is there a reason why the position of the magnifier is not static? Seems to be a bit confusing

Comment: The magnifier is shown on the opposite side so it's not covered by the user's fingers.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities. I would try making a separated working zone at the same screen.

- Horizontal split-screen to get a working area in the lower half
- Color difference between the image of the working area and the real one
- A button to move the partition boundary vertically
- A button with the option to see a working grid in both partitions
- Possibility of zooming in the work area, with or without repercussion
  on the real image. For example:

  - Zoom in both with the usual two-finger gesture
  - Zoom in on just one image with three fingers (or vice-versa)

[image]

The user paints in the work area, the lower part, and visualizes the result in the real image, the upper part.

Comment: Hey @Danielillo, I'm not sure you understood what I meant, Can you re-read my question? Thank you for the answer tho!

Comment: Yes I understood it, answer updated.

Comment: Hey Danielillo! I was asking between the two options I presented (currently, the only one I can integrate within the app structure). The issue we have is that we want a better experience for the user drawing/highlighting.